# Are there any apps that convert files for iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone

So I have an **iPhone 3G**, and it can **no longer** be updated to the **newer versions of software**. So, I was just wondering if there were any apps that would be **compatible** with my phone to convert files and movies so I can watch/view them on my phone.

***PLEASE HELP :)***

Comment: You are looking for conversion software running *on the iPhone* itself?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes can convert movies into an iPhone friendly format. If you have more specific needs, [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is the video converter of choise on OSX.

For other files, applications like [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/goodreader-for-iphone/id306277111?mt=8) or [Air Sharing](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/air-sharing-iphone-nur/id289943355?mt=8) (link to iPhone version, there is also an universal version available) allow reading most "standard" document formats and also offer ways to upload files to your phone without using iTunes.